# Twilio Python: How to call Multiple calls by twilio

Tags: python, twilio

I Want To Call to Multiple phones by Twilio on python
I Just saw Twilio blog but nothing understood to me
this is my script

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "AC723c6c38e7c58a572ce011a652540a42"
auth_token = "REDACTED"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
call = client.calls.create(

    )

print(call.sid)
```

So Can You Tell Me What To Do

Comment: Are you looking for Simultaneous dialing? i.e. you have several phones (or several people) that you want to ring when you receive an incoming call? or you want to do outbound calls to multiple numbers at the same time?

Comment: outbound calls to multiple numbers at same time

Comment: For that you will need to create a conference call than dial out as many participants you want using a loop.

Comment: can you explain what will happen when you dial out multiple numbers? like will they be added to a single call? what's the use case?

Comment: i will change all phones ringtone to happy birthday.and on lift that should say happy birthday aruns and how to make a conference  by twilio

Comment: Can You Give Me The code fast sir because want to suprise

Comment: In this particular use case you would have to call every number, using a loop. Than in the status call back event use the event "answered" to play Message to them. 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallbackevent

Comment: ok thanks i will try

Comment: sorry can you give me the code to make it

Comment: I am not a expert in Python but can give you something in C# but the best way forward is not to be spoon fed. Write some code if you get errors create a new question and I am sure community here will be able to help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.
You should make an array of phone numbers to call and then loop through that array, calling `calls.create` method to make a call to each number in the array passed in as a parameter to `calls.create`.

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "AC723c6c38e7c58a572ce011a652540a42"
auth_token = "REDACTED"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
arr = ['INSERT-NUMBER-TO-CALL', 'INSERT-OTHER-NUMBER-TO-CALL'...]
for num in arr:
    call = client.api.account.calls.create(
        to=num,
        from_='YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER',
        url = 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3'
        )
    print(call.sid)
```

Alternatively, instead of `url` which would contain a link to a file you want to play on the phone, you could use `twiml='<Response><Say>INSERT MESSAGE HERE</Say></Response>',` to have a message played as well. You could use different Amazon Polly voices to customize the voice that speaks the message--[more on that here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say#voice).